# Extract ID number from bbCode tag and retrieve data from the database

Tags: php, regex, foreach

Within the following test string, I have 2 `[image id=""]`.

```
$string = 'This is a regular test string with [image id="1"] within this sentence. The next sentence (this one) will contain another bbCode tag, [image id="3"].';
```

I want to extract the digits within these bbCodes with the help of regex.

```
preg_match_all('~\[image id=(.+?)]~', $string, $results);
foreach($results AS $dataish) {
    echo filter_var($dataish[1], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
}
```

The code above extracts the digit, but instead of `1` and `3`, it's printing out `33`. If I write `$dataish[0]` instead of `$dataish[0]` it will print out `11`.

**Purpose:** I want to get the ID's within the `image` tag to be able to display the right image from the database. `[image id="1"]` will display the image (and of course replacing the bbCode with the image) with ID 1 from the database on the website.

Please keep in mind that the string can also contain only 1 `[image id=""]`. Not always it is containing more than one bbCode of it.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($results AS $dataish){
    $thenumber = filter_var($dataish[1], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
}
echo $thenumber;
```

The problem because $results array have 2 value (1 and 3)  when you do foreach for it, its want to print both but you tell it to print just `$dataish[1];` 
so its print same value 2 times,

The solution is set the output as $thenumber and print it after } (endforeach)

I hope this help you :)

**EDITED**

Here is another Solution @Erik :)

```
preg_match_all('~\[image id=(.+?)]~', $string, $results);
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($results);$i++){
    echo filter_var($results[0][$i], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
}
```

This solution if you want to print more than one output.

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex pattern as shown below:

```
$str = 'This is a regular test string with [image id="1"] within this sentence. The next sentence (this one) will contain another bbCode tag, [image id="3"].';;
preg_match_all('~\[image id="([^"]+)"]~', $str, $result);

print_r($result[1]);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you match all non-quote characters instead of lazily matching?

Comment: @Cameron, FYI - `?` gives no benefit in your approach

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to change your regex to something like this:

```
$re = '/\[image\sid\=\"(\d+?)\"\]/';
$str = 'This is a regular test string with [image id="1"] within this 
sentence. The next sentence (this one) will contain another bbCode tag, [image id="3"].';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
```

You can see my test [here](https://regex101.com/r/IfL1jZ/1) with an explanation on the right hand side